# The declared package dependency does not exist. - uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, .net-native

I have to publish my app on store. For that  I have created .appxupload file. But when I submit this package to developer account it always shows an error like below.

> The declared package dependency does not exist. Dependency: Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.Debug.1.7. Minimum version: 1.7.25531.0. Please upload the .appxupload file generated by Visual Studio for the Store.

.NET Native tool chain is checked by default in the release mode. And also tried by installing different versions of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (v6.0.8,v5.2.2,v5.3.4). Since it contains .NET Native. 
But cant achieve the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by ticking Optimized code checkbox for all architecures

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are actually creating the package as a Debug package.

First check the Build configurations. Click **Build** menu and select **Configuration Manager**. There switch **Active solution configuration** to **Debug** and ensure all projects in the table have **Configuration** column set to `Release` and also check that for every platform in the **Active solution platform** drop down.

Then check if the setting is correct when creating the Store package. Right-click your project, select **Store** and **Create App packages...**, choose **Yes** to build package for Microsoft Store, select **Next**. Choose your app name now and click **Next**. On the **Select and Configure Packages** page check if the **Solution Configuration** is `Release` for all architectures in the bottom table. **Create** the package and try to upload again.

If this does not help, please check if the UWP project has .NET Native compilation enabled for Release build. You can do that by right-clicking the UWP app project in Solution Explorer, choosing **Properties**, switch to the **Build** tab, select `Release` in the `Configuration` drop down and make sure the **Compile with .NET Native tool chain** checkbox is selected and **Define DEBUG constant** is not selected.

Finally you can try to reinstall the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package. Right-click the project, select **Manage NuGet Packages...**, go to **Installed** tab and then uninstall the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package. After that go to **Browse** tab, search for the package again and install it.

One of these solutions should hopefully help :-) .

Comment: " There switch Active solution configuration to Debug ". Hi to debug or release?

Comment: tried with all steps as mentioned above. shows same error.

Comment: also WACK test fails supported API test : ◦API CoCreateInstance in api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type.